# producing df command a grand total specific filesystem

Tags: bash, linux-disk-free

Just need to do some basic thing which I could manage on my own but turned out I have doubt on the result I get...

I need to produce a grand total using df command on specific filesystem on two different servers.

```
ssh server1 df -mP | egrep "/dev/md10|/dev/md11" | sort ; ssh server1 df -mP --total | grep "total" | egrep -v "/dev/md10|/dev/md11
```

The result:

```
/dev/md10                                                   183004016  87303581  95700436      48% /si001c1
/dev/md11                                                   183004016 165986430  17017587      91% /si001c2
total                                                       366565396 253332843 113232554      70%
```

And then I used same command on the 2nd server to get the grand total. My question, the grand total I get seem not right (I'm not sure) and how to produce a grand total by combining both using same command in anyway using single line command or as a basic script in bash. Thanks for the help.

Update:
This is an update after following the guide from @EdmCoff.

```
printf "Grand total: " ; (ssh server1 df -m /dev/md11 ; ssh server2 df -m /dev/md1*) | awk 'a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4;d+=$5/3} END {print a" "b" "c" "d%}'
```

Result:

`Grand total: 549012050 501832399 47179652 92%`

Built a script (re-done):

```
#!/bin/bash
(ssh server1 df -m --no-sync "/dev/md11" ; ssh server2 df -m --no-sync "/dev/md1*") | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | sort > df_udsall
#(cat df_udsall)
printf "\nUDS:\nserver1 & server2\n"
printf "Mounted on       Free space   Disk usage   Use"%%"   Disk state"
while read df_udsall 
do
USAGE=$(echo $df_udsall ; echo $grand_total) | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d"%" -f1
if [[ "$USAGE" -ge " 95" ]]
then
STATUS='CRITICAL'
elif [[ "$USAGE" -ge " 90" ]]
then
STATUS='WARNING'
else
STATUS='OK'
fi
printf "$(echo $df_udsall | awk '{print $6, $4, $3, $5}' > df_udsall_stats)"
column -t df_udsall_stats | perl -ne 'chomp ; printf "\n%-18s %8s %12s %6s %-2s", split / +/' ; printf "`echo -ne $STATUS`"
done < df_udsall
printf "\n\nGrand total " ; cat df_udsall | awk '{b+=$4;c+=$3;d+=$5/3} END {print b" "c" "d "%"}' > grand_total
column -t grand_total | perl -ne 'chomp ; printf "%15s %12s %6s %-2s", split / +/' ; printf "`echo -ne $STATUS`"
rm -f df_udsall df_udsall_stats grand_total
```

The script above need some fine tuning.

Expected result:

```
UDS:
server1 & server2
Mounted on         Free space   Disk usage   Use%   Disk state
/sic1                16202762    166801255    92%   WARNING
/sic2                15648157    167355860    92%   WARNING
/sic3                15256569    167747448    92%   WARNING

Grand total:         47107488    501904563    92%   OK
```

Fixed tripleee script output result:

```
UDS:
server1 & server2
Mounted on         Free space   Disk usage   Use%   Disk state
/sic001c1          92146461     90857556    50% OK
/sic001c2          16873531    166130486    91% WARNING
/sic001c3          16832710    166171307    91% WARNING
/sic001c4          16362388    166641629    92% WARNING

Grand total:       142215090    589800978     81 OK%
```

Comment: There will _always_ be few % of filesystem reserved for the `root` user. So it is not a surprise your total doesn't add up

Comment: For combining your two commands for a grand total, have you considered just using awk? I'm picturing something like `(command for server 1; command for server 2) | awk '/total/ {a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4} END {print a" "b" "c}'`

Comment: @EdmCoff thanks for the command but, I still prefer something more or less getting the same results on both servers as mentioned above. I'm not a Linux guy but fun to play around every day because of my curiosity to try something different from other OS. I try to run command `(ssh server1 df -mP --total /dev/md1* ; ssh server2b df -mP --total /dev/md1*) | awk '/total/ {a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4} END {print a" "b" "c}'` but the result is not as expected. It's a good to learned some new command that I didn't know actually.

Comment: I know `bc` command can do the math but I don't know how to make it a script to calculate all including overall percentage used. Hope someone able to show me or made one. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by grand total (I thought you wanted to combine the totals from the two servers). My suggestion is still awk assuming you want to sum the three columns simultaneously. So, `ssh server1 df -mP /dev/md1* | awk '{a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4} END {print a" "b" "c}'` (i.e. your command _without_ the total and sum all columns) or `ssh server1 df -mP --total /dev/md1* | awk '!/total/ {a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4} END {print a" "b" "c}'` (i.e. include the total in your command, but exclude it in the awk command).

Comment: If you really want to use bc, I would suggest something like `ssh server1 df -mP /dev/md1* | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f 2,2 | paste -sd+ - | bc` where I'm using the `tr` command to replace multiple spaces with one space, the `cut` command to get just the second column of numbers, the `paste` command to reformat the column as num1+num2+num3+etcetera, and the `bc` command to do the math. Obviously, you would need to change the cut command for whichever column you wanted to sum.

Comment: @EdmCoff Thanks for the guide really appreciated. All methods above are okay. Took days and hours for me to understand it actually. After figuring out how to... this is the following command I used `printf "Grand total: " ; (ssh server1 df -m /dev/md11 ; ssh server2 df -m /dev/md1*) | awk 'a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4;d+=$5/3} END {print a" "b" "c" "d%}'`

Comment: That's pretty hideous. Just refactor everything you can into a single Awk script which formats the report (or switch to Perl if Awk is a bad fit; did not read the entire thing very closely).

Comment: @triplee Hideous? Thank you. I have re-edited and because I knew nothing about scripting at least I get the results I wanted. It took days and many hours for my self to understand each commands what it does. I'm thankful to **EdmCoff** for showing 1-line command. I was expecting some script to try and rebuild which is I did (and I do not claim it's mine).

Comment: Don't take it personally, especially if you are scrambling to pick up the basics. I'll see if I could find the time to post an answer with a refactoring of this code. In the meantime, please keep the question merely a question - if you want to post an answer of your own, and perhaps even then mark it as the accepted solution when you can, that's fine.

Comment: @tripleee No, I don't take it personally. Of course it's hideous I don't mind when someone criticize it and re-edit the script, at least at the moment it's just fine with the current 1-line command and the script. What fun you get when you break something that can't be fix. Anyway cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt at refactoring your script into a version where Awk is wholly in control of the calculations and formatting of the output, as suggested in several comments.  I have inlined comments which you might want to remove.

```
#!/bin/bash
# use a loop to reduce duplication of ssh options etc
while read -r server mounts; do
    ssh "$server" df -m --no-sync $mounts </dev/null
done <<\____SERVER__MOUNTS |
    server1 /dev/md10 /dev/md11
    server2 /dev/md12 /dev/md13
____SERVER__MOUNTS
# sed -e /^Filesystem/d inlined into Awk below
sort |
# pipe into awk
awk 'BEGIN { print "UDS:\nserver1 & server2"
        # Maybe use printf here too
        print "Mounted on         Free space   Disk usage   Use%   Disk state"
        fmt="%-18s %8i %12i %6s %-2s"
    }
    function status(num) {
        # Awk conveniently ignores any trailing string
        # so you can compare 95% to 95 numerically
        if (num > 95) result="CRITICAL"
        else if (num > 90) result="WARNING"
        else result="OK"
        return(result)
    }
    ! /^Filesystem/ {
        printf fmt "\n", $6, $4, $3, $5, status($5)

        # EdmCoff''s hack, too lazy to change to legible variable names
        # adapted to defer division until we know the final value of n
        a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4;dd+=$5;n++
    }
    END { d=dd/n;
        printf "\n" fmt "%%\n",
     "Grand total:", c, b, int(d), status(d) }'
```

I obviously have no way to test this with real input, so there are probably minor formatting errors etc.  I hope I captured enough of the logic to at least show you how to implement the body of this processing as an Awk script.

Notice the absence of any temporary files (which your original script would fail to clean up if it was interrupted; [use `trap`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Examples)) and the use of indentation to help you see the loops and conditionals.

Comment: thanks for the script but I do not understand some of its functionality which gives me an error. awk: cmd. line:12: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
 `%-18s %8s %12s %6s %-2s %s
'
                          ^ ran out for this one

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the trailing `%s` you asked about but there could be more; I obviously have no way to test this. If you can supply some realistic test data, it should not be hard to root out any remaining bugs.

Comment: The Awk code is a pretty straightforward one-to-one translation of your shell script but if there is something in particular you don't understand, ask and I'll try to clarify. It really just extracts a few fields from each line which is not a `/^Filesystem/` line and performs the calculations from your code.

Comment: I ran the script, looks fine at first. Then I noticed the script did not see server2 devices, only show server1 device only. Each server have 2 devices. So I changed line #6 & #7 `server1 /dev/md10 /dev/md11` & `server2 /dev/md12 /dev/md13`, server1 OK but not server2. I need the percentage to be round off without a decimal and the disk state threshold. I really don't know how to put that together.

Comment: Again, if you can provide the exact output from `df` it should not be hard to see what to fix. This is currently only really visible to you and me down here in the comments so maybe you should really post a new question with *(1)* the *precise* raw output from `df` from both servers; *(2)* your latest adaptation of the code in this answer; *(3)* the current output from the script, given (1) as input, a description of what's wrong with it, and the expected correct output; and *(4)* a link back to this question (maybe even this specific comment - its date stamp is a link you can copy/paste).

Comment: Probably mention that you are only just beginning to learn Awk and were handed this code and that it's almost right already. And maybe mark this answer as accepted once you manage to get the remaining fixes in.

Comment: Reading back, if you want `/dev/md10` and `/dev/md11` from both servers, maybe just hard-code that in the while loop. For a minimal fix, just list the precise partitions after the server name in the here document (the lines after `<<`) and remove the double quotes around `"$mounts"`

Comment: FWIW a follow-up question was posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201899/df-command-to-single-awk-script but ultimately redirected here as a duplicate because the problem was fairly trivial. See the answer's edit history, too.

Comment: I fixed the output alignment a bit, too. Hope the numbers line up properly now.

Comment: A better way to calculate `d` would be `100.0*c/(c+b)` but I'll leave this as just a comment now.

Comment: I can see the final fixed script alignment bit off and also the % where should not be. Earlier fixed script you made looks fine too but the result almost some what I've expected. I change some part of the script like the % where should it be.